# How to trigger Remote push notification using php when firebase data changed

Tags: php, android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

> **Goal** :- Detect database changes of firebase.

I am using [firebase PHP CLIENT](https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php).

With using firebase php client i am able to

- Connect to firebase node
- Add / update and delete nodes.
- List number of nodes.

Above functionality works perfectly.

But i want to achive functionlity of push notification when user goes offline in to the group as well as person to person chat.

Firebase database is real-time database so, how can i detect the changes of firebase database nodes so i can keep on watch on the message node changes and i should fire my push notification API from php.

The main functionality i want to achive is sending push notifications to group and person to person using firebase chat to mobile platform **( Ios and android )** .

Is there any **alternatives** avaialable for the same? OR any **plugin** which will does the same job?

Or in the another way is there any posibility to send push notifications using **mobile end ( web independent )** ?

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks in advance.